# Issue with Collada export on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: export, performance, osx

did any of you experience a problem with Collada (.dae) export of bigger files? I have a blender project with a number of animations (11 MB in total). I've recently updated Mac OS from 10.14 (Mojave) to 10.15 (Catalina). After the update, I'm not able to export this project to Collada. When I try app freezes on the export window and stays that way forever. Collada file is created but the size of the file is 0B. I've checked console and Blender is getting notification from the system:

> RESOURCE_NOTIFY trigger for Blender [2375] (90009223113 nanoseconds of
>   CPU usage over 127.00s seconds, violating limit of 90000000000
>   nanoseconds of CPU usage over 180.00s seconds)

I was testing versions 2.80, 2.81a and 2.82 (alpha) - problem stays with all of them. Do you have any idea what can be done with this?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. If you can consistently reproduce this bug then it is better if you report a bug on the tracker https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/ or use the report a bug feature from within blender's help menu as it fills in most of the required information about your system.

Comment: Thanks @SamirRahamtalla for the advice. Doing that as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update on the front - I talked with the designer working previously in the project I was struggling with. It looks like it's freezing for quite a long time (around an hour) as there are tons of animations in the file and take this long to handle them in export. I think the outcome of this is missing progress on the export process - what is surprising progress is shown when exporting to eg. .obj.